# How to get the grouping right in R with Plotly

Tags: r, r-plotly, roracle

I have some problem to group my data in Plotly under R. To start with I was using local data from a csv file, reading them with:

```
geogrid_data <- read.delim('geogrid.csv', row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

and the plotting went well, using the following:

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

x <- list(
  title = 'Date'
)
p <- plotly::plot_ly(geogrid_data,
type = 'scatter',
x = ~ts_now,
y = ~absolute_v_sum,
text = paste('Table: ', geogrid_data$table_name,
             '<br>Absolute_v_Sum: ', geogrid_data$absolute_v_sum),
hoverinfo = 'text',
mode = 'lines',
color = list(
  color = colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11,'Spectral'))(
    length(unique(geogrid_data$table_name))
  )
),

transforms = list(
  list(
    type = 'groupby',
    groups = ~table_name
  )
)
) %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE, xaxis = x)
```

Here the output:

[image: Output on grouping of csv data]

Then I was going to alter the data source to an Oracle database table, reading the data as follows, using the ROracle package:

```
# retrieve data into resultSet object
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM GEOGRID_STATS")
# fetch records from the resultSet into a data.frame
geogrid_data <- fetch(rs)
# free resources occupied by resultSet
dbClearResult(rs)
dbUnloadDriver(drv)
# remove duplicates from dataframe (based on TABLE_NAME, TS_BEFORE, TS_NOW, NOW_SUM)
geogrid_data <-  geogrid_data %>% distinct(TABLE_NAME, TS_BEFORE, TS_NOW, NOW_SUM, .keep_all = TRUE)
# alter date columns in place
geogrid_data$TS_BEFORE <- as.Date(geogrid_data$TS_BEFORE, format='%d-%m-%Y')
geogrid_data$TS_NOW <- as.Date(geogrid_data$TS_NOW, format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

and adjusting the plotting to:

```
p <- plotly::plot_ly(
type = 'scatter',
x = geogrid_data$TS_NOW,
y = geogrid_data$ABSOLUTE_V_SUM,
text = paste('Table: ', geogrid_data$TABLE_NAME,
             '<br>Absolute_v_Sum: ', geogrid_data$ABSOLUTE_V_SUM,
             '<br>Date: ', geogrid_data$TS_NOW),
hoverinfo = 'text',
mode = 'lines',
color = list(
  color = colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11,'Spectral'))(
    length(unique(geogrid_data$TABLE_NAME))
  )
),

transforms = list(
  list(
    type = 'groupby',
    groups = geogrid_data$TABLE_NAME
  )
)
) %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE, xaxis = x)
```

Unfortunately, this is leading to some problem with the grouping as it seems.:

[image: Output on grouping of data from database table]

As you can see from the label text when hovering over the data point, the point represents data from **NY_SKOV_PLANTEB_MW_POLY** while the legend is set to show data from **NY_BYGN_MW_POLY**. Looking at other data points in this graph I found a wild mix of points of all sorts in this graph, some of them representing data of **NY_BYGN_MW_POLY**, most of them not.

Also the plotting with respect to the  time line does not work any more, e.g. data are plotted with start on Dec. 11 - Dec. 10 - Dec. 10 - Dec. 12 - Dec. 20 - Dec. 17 - Dec. 16 - Dec. 15.

Where do I go wrong in handling the data, and what do I have to do to get it right?

Comment: Could you share the output of `dput(geogrid_data)`, where `geogrid_data` is the data frame generated using the Oracle database ?

Comment: Yes, that's no problem. The dump from the console can be found here: https://pastebin.com/zzXhpFEE

Only the first 200 rows of the data frame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, one should look at the data... thanks Marco, after your question I did look at my data.

There are some points where I simply assumed things.
The reason why all data plotted fine with data from the csv file is simple. All information manually compiled in the csv file came from information in emails that have been ordered by date. Hence, I compiled the data in the csv file ordered by date and Plotly does not have any problems grouping the data by table_name.

After looking at my data I tidied up, keeping only the data I need to show in the plot and used dplyr to sort the data by time.

```
geogrid_data <- dplyr::arrange(geogrid_data, TS_NOW)
```

It is only by *time* and not by *time* and *table name* because the sorting by *table name* is done anyway by Plotly and the *groupby* statement